# I am not able to deploy this app on wildfly 8.2.0 server. I have changed the .jar file still this error is popping up

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
I have changed the hibernate-jpa .jar file which was corrupted but still the error persists. Also instead of .war file a file folder is formed in deployments.
```

> 15:05:59,806 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."prism2.war".STRUCTURE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."prism2.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to
>   process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "prism2.war"
>         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>   [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>       Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   JBAS018741: Failed to get manifest for deployment
>   "/C:/PRISM_Wildfly_Server/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/prism2.war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"
>         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:78)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:65)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>         ... 5 more
>       Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:715)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:122)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at org.jboss.vfs.util.PaddedManifestStream.read(PaddedManifestStream.java:43)
>   [jboss-vfs-3.2.5.Final.jar:3.2.5.Final]
>         at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:441) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:375)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:409)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:376) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at java.util.jar.Manifest.(Manifest.java:69) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
>         at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:224) [jboss-vfs-3.2.5.Final.jar:3.2.5.Final]
>         at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:208) [jboss-vfs-3.2.5.Final.jar:3.2.5.Final]
>         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.getManifest(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:76)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
>         ... 7 more
>
> 15:05:59,810 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy")
>   failed - address: ([("deployment" => "prism2.war")]) - failure
>   description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"prism2.war\".STRUCTURE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"prism2.war\".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to
>   process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"prism2.war\"
>           Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   JBAS018741: Failed to get manifest for deployment
>   \"/C:/PRISM_Wildfly_Server/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/prism2.war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar\"
>           Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)"}}
>   15:05:59,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "prism2.war"
>   (runtime-name : "prism2.war")
>   15:05:59,989 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
>       JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."prism2.war".STRUCTURE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."prism2.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to
>   process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "prism2.war"

```
15:06:23,348 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."prism2.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."prism2.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "prism2.war"
```

Comment: Please provide more details. A huge error dump with no pieces of information like this is unreadable.

Comment: whenever i'm trying to deploy the app this hibernate-jpa .jar file is getting corrupted. I have added the non corrupted .jar file in the lib folder of standalone as well.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is saying that the JAR / WAR file is corrupt.

It is not possible to say how the file got corrupted, but it could have happened when you downloaded it or deployed it.

Comment: A low quality question, but a decent answer.

Comment: i have replaced the .jar file with a correct one but still the error persist.

Comment: If the problem persists (with those symptoms) then you have not succeeded in replacing the JAR / WAR with a correct one.  Run (for example) `jar -tvf /path/to/file` on the JAR / WAR file on the server to validate the deployed file.  (Or maybe you just need to restart the wildfly server ... )